# Bold and not bold font in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fonts

I want to have bold numbers in axis but non-bold xy labels and title in python matplotlib plot. What I am doing is following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

font = {'family':'Arial','size':45}
mpl.rc('font',**font)
mpl.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':45})
mpl.rc('text',usetex=True)

#mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\boldmath']
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.unicode'] = True
mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 2.75
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0,15.0)
mpl.rcParams['savefig.bbox'] = 'tight'

x = np.linspace(0,6.28,1000)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,np.sin(x),linewidth=7,linestyle='-',color='r',label=r'$u_{\rm rms}$')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$t$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$u_{\rm rms}$')
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=10)
plt.legend(loc=1,fontsize='40')
plt.savefig('a.png')
plt.show()
```

I still get bold everywhere.

[image]

Comment: I think it is because your font size is so big (45!?) that it _appears_ to be bold. Try reducing this to say 15(?) so that you can actually see if it is bold.

Comment: I tried. No difference. Everything just becomes small but remains bold.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the default setting is:

```
font = {'family' : 'normal','weight' : 'bold'} 
plt.rc('font', **font)
```

To change 'weights' from 'bold' to 'normal', run following code in your ploting script :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
font = {'family' : 'normal','weight' : 'normal'}  
plt.rc('font', **font)
```